# How can I prevent `<<- ` from assigning in the global environment?

Tags: r

I've received a function that uses the dreaded `<<-`. Is there any way for me to sandbox it so that it doesn't change the global environment?

For example, I would like to find something so I can run `f()` without it changing the value of x:

```
x <- 0
f <- function()  x <<- 1
f()
x
# [1] 1
```

I tried evaluating it in an environment where the value was already defined:

```
local({
  x <- 2
  f()
})
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Is there a way for me to enclose this to protect the global environment?

Comment: How tedious of a work is to substitute "<<" with "<"? Just sayin'....

Comment: Also if the code you get is more or less independent you could wrap it in a package and only export the functions you need, then `x` should be assigned in the package namespace, unless exported. This would be the cleanest solution.

Comment: ..or create an RDS/RData file with all the objects,create a new session, first load the functions and then the binary file

Comment: @amonk, The code is in a package that's used in a production environment. Changing this code would require changes on the server end which I'm not ready to do yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The assign `<<-` function will first look in the parent environment (of the one the function is) and upwards, in case it won't find any, it will create a new one the global environment.

So the trick is both to wrap `f()` in another function and define it inside, and **also** initialize a variable x in this wrapper function. Then it won't affect your `x` from the global environment:

```
x <- 0
wrapped_f = function(){
  x<-2
  function()  x <<- 1
  f()
  print(paste("new x=", x))
}
wrapped_f()
#### "new x= 1"
print(x)
#### [1] 0
```

And the same but without initializing `x` in the wrapper it will fail:

```
x <- 0
wrapped_f = function(){
  # x<-2
  f <- function()  x <<- 1
  f()
  print(paste("new x=", x))
}
wrapped_f()
#### "new x= 1"
print(x)
#### [1] 1
```

Comment: that's a helluva hack!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I thought the assignment with `<<-` happend in the calling environment, not the environment in which the function was defined. All makes sense now.

Comment: @snaut actually I made some precisions in my answer

Answer (score 2):

One workaround is to use a generator pattern to define the function in a seperate environment. The following code works for me:

```
x <- -1
generator <- function(){
  x <- 0
  function()  x <<- 1
}

f <- generator()

f()
print(x)
# [1] -1
```

Comment: And where is the separate environment defined in your code?

Comment: The local environment of generator.

Comment: In your example you're missing the output of the _final value_ of `x`.

Comment: If you run this code interactively the last line `x` will print the value of `x`, changing it to print.

Answer (score 2):

We can try with `exists` to check if the variable is already defined globally.

```
f <- function()  {
   if(!exists("x"))
      x <<- 1
}
x <- 0
x
#[1] 0

f()

x
#[1] 0
```

Comment: if x already exists and some code later in the f() function needs it, it will return an error no?

Comment: @agenis just keep the assignment statement in the `if` block. Rest of the `f()` code should be outside it, so that it can access `x` if required.